# xml.DocumentElement for each tag

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop, tags, each

I am trying to make my code read each tag and value and got stuck trying to figure it out.

Here is my data:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Word1>Trying</Word1>
<Word2>To</Word2>
<Word3>Learn</Word3>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```css
Word1 => Trying
Word2 => To
Word3 => Learn
```

Comment: You have invalid XML.  A XML object can have only one root.  Try this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
<Word1>Trying</Word1>
<Word2>To</Word2>
<Word3>Learn</Word3>
</Root>

Comment: can you give me full example please with c# code i am kinda new at these stuff and learning

Comment: as @jdweng said. XML Need a unique root node (you can name it whatever you want) and inside this node you can do whatever you want. I suggest you to read a simple tutorial on XML so you can learn the basics.

Comment: thanks i just tried it and it worked fine now ^_^ thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid XML. You can only have one root element in an XML document.

So  the input should be something like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Words>
  <Word1>Trying</Word1>
  <Word2>To</Word2>
  <Word3>Learn</Word3>
</Words>
```

You can parse this in a lot of ways in C#. Two common ways would be using an [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or using the [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) from "LINQ to XML" and then looping over each element or reading them by name or XPath. It's a rather broad subject, but I imagine you only got stuck here because you wanted to have multiple root elements (which again is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
             "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
             "<Root>" +
                "<Word1>Trying</Word1>" +
                "<Word2>To</Word2>" +
                "<Word3>Learn</Word3>" +
             "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Root").Select(x => new {
                word1 = x.Element("Word1").Value,
                word2 = x.Element("Word2").Value,
                word3 = x.Element("Word3").Value
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: what if i want to add 100 words? do i have to add them manually? is there something like foreach?